# Why If statements using logical conditional operators && and != are giving me the wrong result?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, operators, logical-operators

I'm new to programming and I'm learning C#. I'm working on a program that encrypts and decrypts a text entered in a textbox.

I want to make sure that the text and password textboxes are not empty when the user clicks on a button to encrypt or decrypt the text. So, I'm using logical conditional operators `&&` and `!=` to evaluate the textboxes before the code to encrypt the text is run. I seem to be getting the wrong results when I compare the value of the text property of the textboxes against an empty string.

When I click on the encrypt or decrypt buttons without any data in the textboxes the statement: `if (text != " " && encryptPassword != " ")` behaves as if each test is true and run the encrypt or decrypt code anyway. I've tried using `equals`, playing with the parentheses, and reversing the order to no avail. Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CryptoMakerII
{
    public partial class CryptoMakerII : Form
    {

        public CryptoMakerII()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void UpdateControls(string crypto)
        {
            if (crypto == "Encrypt")
            {
                lblEncryptPassword.Visible = false;
                txtEncryptPassword.Visible = false;
                btnEncrypt.Visible = false;
                txtDecryptPassword.Visible = true;
                btnDecrypt.Visible = true;
                lblDecryptPassword.Visible = true;
                lblText.Text = "Encrypted Text";

                //txtDecryptPassword.Text = " ";

                //txtEncryptPassword.Text = " ";

            }
            else
            {

                lblEncryptPassword.Visible = true;
                txtEncryptPassword.Visible = true;
                btnEncrypt.Visible = true;
                txtDecryptPassword.Visible = false;
                btnDecrypt.Visible = false;
                lblDecryptPassword.Visible = false;
                lblText.Text = "Text to Encrypt";
                txtDecryptPassword.Text = " ";
                txtEncryptPassword.Text = " ";





            }
        }
        private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DES_Crypto desCrypto = new DES_Crypto();
            string text = txtText.Text;
            string encryptPassword = txtEncryptPassword.Text;

            if (text != " " && encryptPassword != " ")
            {
                string encryptedText = desCrypto.EncryptString(text, encryptPassword);
                txtText.Text = encryptedText;
                UpdateControls("Encrypt"); 

            }
            else

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter text to encrypt and password");
            }

        }



        private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DES_Crypto desCrypto = new DES_Crypto();
            if (txtText.Text != " " && txtDecryptPassword.Text != " ")

                if (txtDecryptPassword.Text == txtEncryptPassword.Text)
                     {
                        string decryptedText = desCrypto.DecryptString(txtText.Text, txtDecryptPassword.Text);
                        txtText.Text = decryptedText;
                        UpdateControls("Decrypt");
                     }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The password is incorrect!");
                }               
                else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter password to decrypt");
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `if(crypto)`...

Comment: No I didn't, Michal. But user3144325 saw my error and corrected me. I should have used string.IsNullOrEmpty(string) method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the string exactly equals 1 whitespace character, not checking if it is empty. C# has a built in method to check if a string is empty or not:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
```

So instead of

```
if (txtText.Text != " " && txtDecryptPassword.Text != " ")
```

Try

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtText.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDecryptPassword.Text))
```